# Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read React Native (Android )

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have been using Xcode simulator for project and now I am trying to run  Android simulator for the same project and It shows me this error

the application is working perfectly on Ios Simulator.

[image]

Any Clues what's the problem, or maybe solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the Issue by Renaming `index.ios.js` to `index.js`